# How to change font-weight in Jumbotron Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I change the font weight of the `.jumbotron` and paragraphs in `.jumbotron`?
I do not want my `font-weight` so big.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid landing-page">
        <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
            <h1>Embroider<span class="eze">eze</span></h1>
            <p>Branding <span class="eze">&#9679;</span> Promotional Items <span class="eze">&#9679;</span> Reflective Tape <span class="eze">&#9679;</span> Gifts</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    color: #dbdbdb;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

Also, font size changes do not work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pa07so3e/.  It seems to work as expected to me.  I made the `font-weight: 900` to illustrate it changes.  This Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pa07so3e/1/ shows smaller font

Comment: maybe I have the CSS linked wrong, ill check. (edit) Still not working - CSS is linked correctly

Comment: @user2796515 it doesn't seem like the font weight has changed at all in those images, only the font size did.

Comment: This one the `h1` and the `p` are changed: https://jsfiddle.net/pa07so3e/3/  compare to this: https://jsfiddle.net/pa07so3e/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default, bootstrap has some styles for h1 and P. If you want to override try with this

```
.jumbotron h1{

font-weight: 800;

}

.jumbotron p{

font-weight: 800;

}
```

Comment: It seems like this works, but my text doesn't change in the ranges where font-weight is between 100 and 500

Comment: @WihanUys try to increase the font size

Answer (score 1):

you can check this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .jumbotron h1 {
      color: #dbdbdb;
      background-color: transparent;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 100px;
      font-weight: 200;
      font-size: 20px;

    }

    .jumbotron p {
      color: #dbdbdb;
      background-color: transparent;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 100px;
      font-weight: 200;
      font-size: 20px;

    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
      <![endif]-->
  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid landing-page">
      <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
        <h1>Embroider
          <span>eze</span>
        </h1>
        <p>Branding
          <span>&#9679;</span> Promotional Items
          <span>&#9679;</span> Reflective Tape
          <span>&#9679;</span> Gifts</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for adjusting font weight in a BootStrap 4 Jumbotron:

Similar syntax - say you create a class in your css file as below;

```
   .jumbotron_text { font-weight: 600; }
```

And apply it to the p tag inside your jumbotron div as below;

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <p class=jumbotron_text">Some text here </p>
    </div>
```

Notice I use 600 ( the range is 100,200, 300, 400, 500,600, 700, 800,900 ).

Most fonts map normal to 500 and bold to 700.

Other numbers are an approximation by the browser unless its available in the font specifically.